# Можем ли мы стоять на горизонте?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, лексическая-сочетаемость

Грамотно ли звучат словосочетания "стоим на горизонте", "стоять на горизонте"?

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, тёзка! Дайте, пожалуйста, контекст или опишите ситуацию. "Горизонт" — слово многозначное. *Медленно всходила красная, угрюмая луна, тёмная туча, формой подобная рыбе, неподвижно **стояла на горизонте**, разрезая диск луны, и луна казалась чашей, полной крови* (Максим Горький. Собака).

Comment: Добрый день, тезка))) рассказываю) это перевод песни с английского, дословно- "стоим на горизонте, где земля столкнулась с небом". Я понимаю, что мы не можем стоять на горизонте. Это просто невозможно, и бессмысленно звучит, на мой взгляд

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова У Горького туча стояла не на ногах, а стояла - остановилась, зависла в полете на горизонте(в стороне горизонта, наблюдатель смотрит на тучу). То есть горизонт имеет место быть, только со стороны наблюдателя. А если мы стоим... то не ясно кто наблюдатель. Мб фотография? "мы стоим на горизонте, где земля столкнулась с небом" - вдобавок еще плеоназм, так как горизонт - это линия, где земля сомкнулась с небом).

Comment: @Буратино Плеоназм — это когда единая фраза (в простом предложении). Здесь может быть пояснение.

Comment: @oleedd ладно, ладно, я не разбираюсь в этой терминологии, но видимо это вот это - Ляпалиссиады. В общем фразы из разряда "капитан очевидность".

Answer (score 2):

Горизонт (греч. *horízōn* (*horízontos*) — ограничивающий] — видимая граница (линия кажущегося соприкосновения) неба с земной или водной поверхностью; пространство неба над этой границей (из БТС).

Есть насколько вариантов перевода песни "Stand on the horizon".

• Я стою на линии горизонта,
Я хочу перешагнуть ее с тобой.
Но когда солнце так низко,
То все вокруг объято холодом
На линии горизонта.

• Я стою на горизонте,
я хочу перешагнуть его с тобой,
но когда солнце опускается,
всё на горизонте становится холодным.

• Я стою на горизонте,
я хочу перешагнуть его вместе с тобой,
но когда солнце садится,
всюду холод.

"Герой песни находится в поиске смысла жизни, и он не представляет его без любимого человека" (Е. А. Осокина. Вербализация образа солнца в европейских и азиатских лингвокультурах (на материале современного песенного дискурса)).
Герой стоит на границе, на черте, на линии принятия важного решения...
Красиво. Понятно.

Есть книги: "Перешагнуть горизонт" (Althessa Oldoak), "Заглянуть за горизонт" (Лариса Агафонова).
Есть письмо Андрея Белого, адресованное Блоку (1905):

> Я страж дозорный, стою на горизонте, трубу золотую приложив к устам, извещаю мир: "Летит облако верное и истинное во веки веков".